# php pear email works with gmail smtp, but no emails get sent with local server

Tags: php, email, pear

I just upgraded to ubuntu 12.04, installed pear, mail and mail_mime. I am using a sample code below. It used to work, but I am not sure If I had some changes made in php.ini. It has been sometime since my last setup. I tested with gmail smtp server, and all works good.

```
<?
        include('Mail.php');
        include('Mail/mime.php');

        // Constructing the email
        $sender = "Leigh <leigh@no_spam.net>";                              // Your name and email address
        $recipient = "Leigh <leigh@no_spam.net>";                           // The Recipients name and email address
        $subject = "Test Email";                                            // Subject for the email
        $text = 'This is a text message.';                                  // Text version of the email
        $html = '<html><body><p>This is a html message</p></body></html>';  // HTML version of the email
        $crlf = "\n";
        $headers = array(
                        'From'          => $sender,
                        'Return-Path'   => $sender,
                        'Subject'       => $subject
                        );

        // Creating the Mime message
        $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);

        // Setting the body of the email
        $mime->setTXTBody($text);
        $mime->setHTMLBody($html);

        $body = $mime->get();
        $headers = $mime->headers($headers);

        // Sending the email
        $mail =& Mail::factory('mail');
        $mail->send($recipient, $headers, $body);
?>
```

Is there something I am missing? Should I change sendmail_path in php.ini? or something?

Comment: can you sent emails with your setup at all? Open a terminal and type: `mail your@emailaddre.ss [enter] test [enter] test [enter] [enter] ctrl+d` and check your email.

Comment: @John I tried, but it said mailutils not installed. But even before trying to install it, I learned that php does not come with the sendmail default and I had to install it. I installed it and now it sends mail (takes almost 10-15 seconds though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your errors of that from the error.log file
of apache  check

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/apapche2/error.log
```

here you can find your error of sending mails

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear

sudo pear install mail

sudo pear install Net_SMTP

sudo pear install Auth_SASL

sudo pear install mail_mime
```

any try to send mail now :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There was nothing in the error log. I had installed all but the Auth_SASL, and did not work. AFter that I installed sendmail and now it sends mail but very very slow. Any idea why it takes so long? I used to have it working pretty well in my earlier installation